# big o notation for nested for loop

Tags: java, big-o

How would I find the big o notation for the nested for loop of the following code?

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < N; i *= 2)
   for(int j =0; j <i; j++)
     sum++;
```

I believe the outer loop is log(n) and the inner loop is N, so isn't the answer n*log(n)? If my answer is correct, can we assume that j

Comment: @Luminous It's `i *=2`, not `i += 2`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That's right... just a slight oversight. >.<

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer would be correct if the inner loop ran from zero to `N`. However, it runs from zero to `i`, which in turn runs as consecutive powers of two.

Therefore, the number of times the inner block `sum++` would get executed could be computed as a sum of the form

```
1+2+4+8+16+...
```

with log<sub>2</sub>N terms.

This is a geometric series. Computing the s[um of its first log<sub>2</sub>N terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum) gives the correct answer is O(N).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by log2N terms?

Comment: @user2832367 The number of terms is the number of items being added together (in my example, that's five terms - 1, 2, 3, 8, and 16). It is the same as the number of iterations fo the *outer* loop. It depends on `N` as the binary logarithm, i.e. the power to which 2 must be raised in order to produce `N`. Strictly speaking, the number of terms is the binary logarithm rounded up to the next integer.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you can't find the answer mathematically, how about empirical evidence?

```
for (int N = 1; N > 0; N <<= 1) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i *= 2)
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            sum++;
    System.out.println(N + ": " + sum);
}
```

*Output*

```
1: 0
2: 1
4: 3
8: 7
16: 15
32: 31
64: 63
128: 127
256: 255
512: 511
1024: 1023
2048: 2047
4096: 4095
8192: 8191
16384: 16383
32768: 32767
65536: 65535
131072: 131071
262144: 262143
524288: 524287
1048576: 1048575
2097152: 2097151
4194304: 4194303
8388608: 8388607
16777216: 16777215
33554432: 33554431
67108864: 67108863
134217728: 134217727
268435456: 268435455
536870912: 536870911
1073741824: 1073741823
```

When you double `N`, you double the number of times `sum++` is executed, so answer is: **O(N)**